# fetch-mock calls the actual API instead of mocking the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, jestjs, fetch-api

Given this code:

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch')
module.exports = function suggestions (...args) {
  // some error handling code
  return fetch(MY_ENDPOINT)
}
```

I have found that when using fetch-mock like this:

```
require('isomorphic-fetch')
const fetchMock = require('fetch-mock/es5/server')
fetchMock.mock(MY_ENDPOINT, [{}, {}])

describe('My spec', () => {
  it('fakes a request to my endpoint', async () => {
      const myData = await myCode(...args) // calls fetch with my endpoint
      expect(myData).toEqual([{}, {}])
  })
})
```

I would expect the mock to give me the response I set up which is `[{},{}]`, instead it calls the real API and returns the response from it.

Also, if I try to use `fetch-mock` instead of `fetch-mock/es5/server` I get the error:

```
/Users/localuser/lendi/ldp-domain-integration/node_modules/fetch-mock/src/lib/fetch-handler.js:57
    FetchMock.generateResponse = async function (response, url, opts) {
                                       ^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

I use jest with `babel` and `babel-jest` along with `node v6.13.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the Syntax error is that async functions are not supported in Node version 6.

Try updating Node to the latest version.

Comment: I am using it with the aws lambda and lambda-tester package which requires node 6.